# What does a hyphen at end of a term mean

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to understand the statement and I can't find any thing about the `-1/4` at the the end of the object term. I've tried searching but I'm not even sure what to search for.

```
exists(A,object(B,A,apple,countable,na,eq,1)-1/4).
```

Comment: That term is equivalent to `exists(A, '-'(object(B,A,apple,countable,na,eq,1), '/'(1,4)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of exists/2 are two terms in pair notation. One term being `object(_A,A,apple,countable,na,eq,1)` and the other being the `1/4`. You can see this if you try the following query:

```
   ?- exists(A,X-Y).
X = object(_A,A,apple,countable,na,eq,1),
Y = 1/4
```

And since the second term is an arithmetic expression, you can evaluate it using is/2:

```
   ?- exists(A,X-Y), Z is Y.
X = object(_A,A,apple,countable,na,eq,1),
Y = 1/4,
Z = 0.25
```

The functor (-)/2 is often used to denote pairs. As pointed out by @lurker in the comments, the canonical form is `-(X,Y)` but since (-)/2 is defined as an infix operator in Prolog, both notations are equivalent. To see that consider the following query:

```
   ?- X-Y = -(X,Y).

true
```

Comment: @lurker: Thanks for the hint. I updated my post accordingly :-)

Comment: @lurker, the canonical form is the unquoted `-`, not the quoted one.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this.:)